# Method Generics bound restriction with Class Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a somewhat strong typed API:

```java
class PropertyType<T> { ... }
class SubType1<T> extends PropertyType<T> { ... }
class SubType2<T> extends PropertyType<T> { ... }

class PropertyHandler<K extends PropertyType<?>> { 

    // Here, the V generics is not related to the property type,
    // hence the value is not typed
    public <V> getValue(K prop) { ... }

    // In this case, we have correct typing, but T is not bounded to K
    public <V, T extends PropertyType<V>> getValue(T prop) { ... }

    // This would be a solution, but it doesn't compile because K is a type variable
    public <V, T extends K & PropertyType<V>> getValue(T prop) { ... }
}
```

And that is how it would be used:

```java
PropertyHandler<SubType1<?>> ph = new PropertyHandler<>();

// I want to allow this
SubType1<Integer> p1 = new SubType1<>();
SubType1<Boolean> p2 = new SubType1<>();
Integer v1 = ph.getValue(p1);
Boolean v2 = ph.getValue(p2);

// I don't want to allow this
SubType2<Integer> p3 = new SubType2<>();
Boolean v3 = ph.getValue(p3);
```

Is there a way to solve this ? Maybe it's some architecture problem that can be handled differently ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question right, but could you not change "class PropertyHandler<K extends PropertyType<?>>" to "class PropertyHandler<K extends PropertyType<X>>" and then use "public <V, T extends X>"? As it seems you're looking for a way to limit the K value to only what is set in <?> of the property handler.

Comment: Yes it's exactly that. However your suggestion does not work: "class PropertyHandler<K extends PropertyType<X>>" this does not compile, until you also specify the X as type variable, which is not what I want...

Comment: Why do you not want to make the X a type variable?

Comment: I would have to declare "class PropertyHandler<X, K extends PropertyType<X>>" and then define X when I create an instance. Since my class hierarchy is a bit more complex, I have for instance "class SpecialProp<T> extends PropertyType<T> { ... }", and I would like to bound my getValue method to SpecialProp without restricting T.

Answer (score 1):

The return type for `getValue()` must be added to the generic signature of `PropertyHandler`.  Otherwise, there is no way for `PropertyHandler` to infer the `getValue()` return type from the generic definition of `PropertyType`.

Therefore, either assign both return type and property type to the `PropertyHandler` generic signature, or flip it by specifying the return type in `PropertyHandler`, and having `PropertyHandler` ensure the correct `PropertyType` parameter type, like this:

```
class PropertyType<T, H extends PropertyHandler<T>> {
    public T getValue() { ... }
}
class IntegerType extends PropertyType<Integer, PropertyHandler<Integer>> { ... }
class BooleanType extends PropertyType<Boolean, PropertyHandler<Boolean>> { ... }

class PropertyHandler<V> {
    public <T extends PropertyType<V, PropertyHandler<V>>> V getValue(T prop) {
        return prop.getValue();
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```
PropertyHandler<Integer> ph = new PropertyHandler<>();
IntegerType p1 = new IntegerType();
Integer v1 = ph.getValue(p1); // works fine
BooleanType p3 = new BooleanType();
Boolean v3 = ph.getValue(p3); // compile time error
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By doing this, it would allow to restrict the usage of PropertyHandler to some kind of data (ie Integer), but not to the kind of types (ie IntegerType). I edited my original post to include some generics in the subclasses.